# Producing .png images with Gnuplot of large data files

Tags: gnuplot

I have data files from 20 GB to 50 GB each. I want to draw plots using theses files which I later use to make small videos. My Gnuplot script is as follows:

```
unset xtics
unset ytics
unset key
unset border
set xrange [0:12.8]
set yrange [0:7.2]
set cbrange [0:1]
set size ratio -1
set term png

file = "hugeDataFile.dat"

sizeX = 1280
sizeY = 720
lines = sizeX*sizeY
numberOfImages = 1500 

do for [i=1:numberOfImages]{
    set terminal png size sizeX, sizeY
    set output sprintf('%05d.png', i)
    start = (i-1)*lines+1
    end = i*lines
    plot file every ::start::end u 1:2:3 pt 5 ps 0.4 pal
}
```

The problem is, it takes more than 48 hours to plot those 1500 .png images from a 31 GB data file. Is there any way to accelerate that process? Can I make the Gnuplot script more efficient?

Comment: have you profiled the run? Does this use all available CPUs on your system, or just 1 CPU at 100%? If the later, then there are unix/linux techniques with bash scripting that would allow you to run multiple processes of gnuplot to use any/all available CPUs which should divide the runtime by numOfAvailCPUS. (Sorry, I don't know enough about gnuplot to offer any fixes internally). Good luck.

Comment: Is it important for you to plot every point? I don't think that someone can tell the difference if such large files were plotted using every point or every, say, 10th point. Try to plot with `every N::start::end`.

Comment: @MichaelO. Every plot contains 1280 x 720 points. If I do what you suggested with `N=2` the plot does not look good anymore.

Comment: @Samuel then try to do what @shellter suggested, create several gnuplot scripts with different start and end, for example, `do for [i=1:500]`, `do for [i=501:1000]` etc, and launch them in different terminals.

Comment: I agree with the comments above about creating several gnuplot scripts to increase efficiency. What you are doing is *not* a serial process right? No plot depends on the previous one to be created, so you should be parallelizing this in any way you can. In addition, in the past I had problems with gnuplot running slow because the actual input data files were *huge*, and just the loading part takes time. For that, you could also setup a bash script (or even in gnuplot) to cut the 50GB file in smaller pieces, then run a few gnuplot scripts. Hope this helps!